# Question about voltage in parallel circuits

Tags: voltage, inductor, parallel

[image]

So here is my schematic diagram at t < infinity for an RL circuit. I am given only a voltage source. My question is that since the voltage is connected to both ends of the circuit in parallel with the branches, then the voltage going across the 3 branches is 18 V. Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three paths from your voltage source have a "voltage drop" of 18v.  Each path has only one resistor so the only unknown in each path is the current (which will be different in each path.
You'll be able to calculate resistance from the standard parallel resistance formula or you can divide voltage by the total current you calculate (sum of the current for the three branches).

Answer (score 0):

There are three parallel resistors in your schematic. Branch currents can be calculated directly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkjCD1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The image below will help you identify the two nodes.

[image]